# Making a principal bundle into a covering space

Tags: smooth-manifolds, covering-spaces, principal-bundles

Suppose $\pi : P\rightarrow M$ is a principal $G$-bundle. I want to make this into a covering map by changing the topology of $P$.

By local triviality we can find for each $x\in M$ an open $U\subset M$ containing $x$ such that there is a diffeomorphism $\phi: \pi^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U\times G$. We can choose the following topology on $U\times G$: the opens are just $V\times \{g\}$ where $V\subset U$ open and $g\in G$ and then take all possible unions and intersections as the topology. We also have to add $V\times \emptyset$ to make it into a topology. Then define the topology on $P$ by requiring that $\phi$ is diffeomorphism.

Then we have that $\pi^{-1}(U)=\cup_{g\in G}\phi^{-1}(U\times \{g\})$ and then we can say that $\pi : P\rightarrow M$ is a covering.

*Question*

I am not sure at all if this construction actually really works, it is just an idea. I hope someone can clarify some things.

*Edit*

Suppose that we have a flat connection on $P$, i.e. a vector sub bundle $H\subset TP$ such that $d\pi_p|_{H_p}:H_p\rightarrow T_{\pi(p)} M$ is an isomorphism for all $p\in P$. Flatness implies that this distribution is integrable, using Frobenius. Now I want to use this to make $P$ a covering space for $M$. Let $p\in P$ and $U\subset P$ open containing $p$ such that we have local coordinates $(\chi_1,...,\chi_k,...,\chi_n)$ where $k=\dim M$ and $n=\dim P$ and $$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \chi_1}|_q,...,\frac{\partial}{\partial \chi_k}|_q\right)$$ is a basis for $H_q$ for all $q\in U$. If we look at $\pi(U)\subset M$ (which is open) and then take the inverse image, we get $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U))=\cup_{g\in G}U\cdot g$. Each $U\cdot g$ is open and they are disjoint so we have almost a covering, but we also need that $\pi$ is a homeomorphism from each $U\cdot g$ to $\pi(U)$. From here I am stuck. Any ideas how to change the topology of $P$ and make it work?

Comment: This doesn't work how I think you want it to, at least in general: The space $V \times \{g\} \subset \pi^{-1}(U)$ depends on the choice of trivialization $\phi$. (There's also the issue that, unless $G$ is countable, the resulting topology isn't second countable, so by some reckoning it isn't even a manifold.) Depending on what you have in mind, though, you might be able to recover some version of this if you have preferred trivializations (for example, if the bundle is just $M \times G$ or the canonical bundle $A \to A / G$ associated to a homogeneous space).

Comment: @Travis I have edited my question, I added more structure to $P$. Do you think we can make a covering space now?

Comment: Note that a smooth covering space map is always between manifolds of the same dimension (discrete fibers)

Comment: @Max So it is not possible to make a smooth covering space map if $\dim P > \dim M$? But is it possible to have just continuous covering space map?

Comment: No, the distinction between smooth and continuous isn't the key fact. Since (small) open sets in $P$ and $M$ have to be homeomorphic, their dimensions have to match.

Comment: @Max you can change the dimension by changing the topology, so your argument doesnt show that it is not possible.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to point out that you'd have to pretty drastically change the topology. For example, say you had circle fibers. You'd have to change the topology to make those fibers discrete, but then the fibers would fail to be second countable. (I think this is a part of what Travis was getting at.)

Comment: @Max it is true that it will not be second countable, but I only want a covering space